# Target date from birthday

Tags: javascript

I would like to create from 3 variables:

```
var Day = 20;
var Month = 12;
var Year = 1960;
```

The birthday in the following format in JavaScript:

```
Birthday = 12/20/1960;
```

Then I would like to set up a target date with 60 years later after the Birthday:

```
Target = 12/20/2020;
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: `Birthday = Day + "/" + Month + "/" + Year` and then to get 60 more years, you have to wait until 2020 before you run the same code once again.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer only because it's Christmas:

```
var Target = Day + "/" + Month + "/" + (Year + 60);
```